# Wrong element focused in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onfocus

In my javascript web application I've a table with custom cells, with read mode (Simple label) and edit mode on double-click (input). When I'm in edit mode, the focus is setted on the div that contains the input (in td) and then I can use TAB to move to another cell. When I'm in read mode, the focus is setted ever on the div that contains the label and I can use TAB and Arrows to move to another cell.
This works perfect in Explorer, but in Chrome, in read mode, the focus is different: is setted ever on table element and then I can't use TAB and Arrows to move to another cell..
I've tried also force focus setting an Interval:

```
$("#iddiv").focus()
```

The problem is just on Chrome

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class='...'>
<label></label>
</div>
</td>
......
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an attribute of `tabindex="0"` on the `<div>`s (technique found [in this blog post](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/01/onfocus-and-onblur-for-divs-in-fx/))

```js
$(function() {
  $('div[tabindex]').first().focus();
});
```

```css
td {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}
td label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 1</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 2</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 3</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 4</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 5</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 6</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 7</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 8</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 9</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div tabindex="0">
          <label>Cell 10</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```